# C do while loop repeats 2 times before checking condition

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

Why my `do`/ `while` loop repeats 2 times before it checks condition?

```
int main() {

    char quit;
    quit = getchar();
    do {
        printf("Next state: ");
        clock_t start = clock();
        count_values(a, b);
        clock_t end = clock();
        float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        print_state(b);
        printf("\nTime: %f\n", seconds);
        swap(a, b);
        printf("Press enter to print next generation. To quit, enter 'q'.");
        quit = getchar();
    } while(quit != 'q');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Only after loop has repeated 2 times, `getchar()` waits for input, why? How to fix it?

Comment: `getchar()` leaves the newline after the first call which you then read on the second call.

Comment: @dunlop It is because thsi call of getchar quit = getchar(); also reads the new line character '\n';

Comment: Because your first input is `q` and a newline character. So your `quit` equals `q` from the first `getchar` outside the loop *until* you call `getchar` second time within the loop, which is overwriting it with newline.

Comment: Easy fix, use `fgets()`.

Comment: Aside: little reason to use `float seconds`.  Suggest `double` types and math.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably giving the input *manually*, therefore when you press the `Enter` key, a newline character is left behind which is then consumed by the second `getchar()` call.

To bypass this, you can use `fgets()`.

```c
   char quit[100];

   fgets(quit, sizeof(quit), stdin);

    do {
        printf("Next state: ");
        clock_t start = clock();
        clock_t end = clock();
        float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("\nTime: %f\n", seconds);
        printf("Press enter to print next generation. To quit, enter 'q'.");
        fgets(quit, sizeof(quit), stdin);
    } while(quit[0] != 'q');
```

While the above code should do the job, one can easily *trick* the program, by typing anything that starts with `q`.

The solution would be to use `strcmp()` to check that the string only contains `"q"`.

Note that `fgets()` also stores the newline character in the buffer, to bypass that you need to replace it with a **NULL** byte.

```c
   char quit[100];

    do {
        printf("Next state: ");
        clock_t start = clock();
        clock_t end = clock();
        float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("\nTime: %f\n", seconds);
        printf("Press enter to print next generation. To quit, enter 'q'.");
        fgets(quit, sizeof(quit), stdin);
        quit[strcspn(quit, "\n")] = '\0'; /* get rid of \n */
    } while(strcmp(quit, "q") != 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

It does *not* repeat twice before checking the condition.
You can check that by slightly modifying your code, which also makes it a minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(char c) {
    printf("Testing input: %d\n", c);
    return c != 'q';
}

int main() {
    char quit;
    quit = getchar();
    do {
        printf("Press enter to print next generation. To quit, enter 'q'.\n");
        quit = getchar();
    } while(test(quit));

    return 0;
}
```

You can see that the input is already being tested after the first loop. It is not `'q'`, if you type `q` then `[enter]`. The `q` will be consumed by the `quit = getchar();` *before* the loop. Then the newline character (decimal 10) will be checked in the condition, and it is not `q`.

So your assumption was wrong.